# how to resolve the problem Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase/storage' in next.js (already done yarn add firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

i want to implement firebase to my next.js file but it keep getting popup module not found

apply firebase in this file

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client';
import { EmojiHappyIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { CameraIcon,VideoCameraIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import{  useRef } from "react";
import { db } from "../../firebase";
import firebase from "../../firebase";
function InputBox() {
    const [session]=useSession();
    const inputRef=useRef(null);

    const sendPost = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();


    if(!inputRef.current.value) return;

    db.collection('posts').add({
        message: inputRef.current.value,
        name: session.user.name,
        email: session.user.email,
        image: session.user.image,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })

      inputRef.current.value="";
    };
```

firebase file

```
import firebase from "./firebase";
import "firebase/storage";
```

my const firebaseConfig is correct already

```
const app = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : firebase.app() ;
const db = app.firestore();
const storage= firebase.storage();

export { db, storage };
```

Answer (score 0):

code is for `firebase v8` and you have `firebase v9` package

downgrade version :

1. npm rm firebase //remove current
2. npm install firebase@8.9 //install firebase8

Comment: try installing the firebase v8.9 but still giving the same error